# inconsistent bad mask error

Tags: cisco, switch, ipv4, ip-address, packet-tracer

in packet tracer i was assigning: 
83.174.16.164 255.255.255.248 to 3560 switch
which shouldn't throw an error of bad mask given that it is in the usable range:

```
Address:   83.174.16.160         01010011.10101110.00010000.10100 000
Netmask:   255.255.255.248 = 29  11111111.11111111.11111111.11111 000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.7               00000000.00000000.00000000.00000 111
=>
Network:   83.174.16.160/29      01010011.10101110.00010000.10100 000 (Class A)
Broadcast: 83.174.16.167         01010011.10101110.00010000.10100 111
HostMin:   83.174.16.161         01010011.10101110.00010000.10100 001
HostMax:   83.174.16.166         01010011.10101110.00010000.10100 110
Hosts/Net: 6
```

[image]

so i am just wondering what was causing the error? because it ended up letting me put the mask in after i trying a couple of times.
thanks for taking the time to read my post any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mask you were trying to use really is a bad mask. You were trying to use 255.255.**225**.248.

You simply had a typographical error that you eventually corrected.

It happens, and it is a big reason to have a peer review of your work before putting it into production.

Comment: i think i might be blind but i cant see where i made the typographical error

Comment: In the third octet, you have two hundred **twenty**-five, not two hundred **fifty**-five.